# Phonegap - events such as focus(),blur() not called in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, dom-events

I have just started using Phonegap, I wanted to clear the textbox content when the user clicks on the textbox.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" class="clear" id="dateVal" name="date" value="date" onblur="clear();"/>/
```

**JavaScript**

```
function clear() {
        document.getElementsByTagName('input').value = '';
    }
```

But the clear function is not getting called. Also, just tried putting `alert` in `clear()`
function(did not help). Everything else working okay. Any help would be appreciated.

**Full HTML Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html>   <head>
    <title>Age Calculator</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.8.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

    function onDeviceReady() { 
        alert('welcome');
    }
        function calAge() {         
          var x = confirm('Click here to calculate the age'); 
          if(x == true) {
           document.getElementById('ageId').style.display = block';
          } else {
              navigator.app.exitApp();      }
         }   
        function submitValues() {
                var todaysDate = new Date();
                var y = todaysDate.getFullYear();
                var m = todaysDate.getMonth() + 1;
                var d = todaysDate.getDate() + 1;
                var myYear = document.getElementById('yearVal').value;
                var myMonth = document.getElementById('monthVal').value;
                var myDate = document.getElementById('dateVal').value;
                var myYear = (y-myYear);
                var myMonth = (m-myMonth);
                var myDate = (d-myDate);
                document.getElementById('ageId').style.display = 'none';    
                document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'You are '+myYear+'years '+myMonth+' months and '+myDate + ' days old :-)';
                            }   function clear() {      document.getElementsByTagName('input').value = '';  }
    </script>   </head>   <body>
    <button onclick="calAge();">Age Calculator</button> <br>
    <div id="ageId" style="display:none;">
        <b>Please Enter your Date Of Birth in (dd/mm/yyyy) format:</b>
        <input type="text" class="clear" id="dateVal" name="date" value="date" onblur="clear();"/>/
        <input type="text" class="clear" id="monthVal" name="month" value="month" />/
        <input type="text" class="clear" id="yearVal" name="year" value="year" />
        <input type="button" value="submit" onclick = "submitValues();" />
    </div>
    <div id="result">
    </div>   </body> </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In HTML5 there is a `placeholder` attribute.
Ex:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Date" id="dateVal" name="date" />
```

We could use this to get what I desired.
Thanks, might be helpful to somebody.